# Product and intersection of comaximal ideals in noncommutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

So, exercise 4.5. of Chapter III of Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0" states the following:

> Let $I, J$ be ideals in a ring, such that $I + J =
> (1)$. Prove that $IJ = I\cap J$.

(We say that ideals $I,J$ such that $I + J = (1)=R$ are *comaximal*).

Now, I have been able to prove the statement for the commutative case, but is it possible to prove it for noncommutative rings? If not, are there counterexamples? The curious thing is that the questions I found here about this problem all assume that $R$ is commutative, so I am wondering if there is actually something missing in Aluffi's exercise.

Comment: Actually we have $IJ+JI=I\cap J$ (provided that $R$ is unital).

Comment: Simple counterexamples for $IJ=I\cap J$ in the non-commutative case can be found in the ring $k\left<X,Y\right>$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result does not hold in general in the non-commutative case. Let $R$ be the ring of upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$, and for each $i\leqslant j\in\{1,2\}$ let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix whose entries are $1$ in the ${ij}$-th position and $0$ everywhere else. Now, let $I$ be the two-sided ideal $\{\lambda E_{12}+\mu E_{22}:\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ and let $J$ be the two-sided ideal $\{\lambda E_{11}+\mu E_{12}:\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. Certainly $I+J=R$, since $1_R=E_{22}+E_{11}$, and we have $I\cap J=\{\lambda E_{12}:\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. However, we have $IJ=\{0\}$, so this gives the desired counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @ConcreteSwanDive my pleasure! :)